# Display navigation bar on android

Tags: android, sony

My android (4.0.4) phone (xperia neo L) comes with physical buttons for the 4 primary actions (back, home, settings, search)

Is it possible to make these available within the OS also?

Comment: What does "make these available within the OS" mean?

Comment: make it available within the screen so that I dont use the physical buttons.

Comment: Some smartphones don't have these physical buttons instead they are available within the touch panel/screen. Unfortunately mine doesn't have.

Comment: @John So wat you trying to do iz customize the OS to integrate the menu function iniside OS?? which can be used via some status bar type of area. Pulling from upper side type of menu??

Comment: exactly like status bar kind of. but i dont want to do programmatic ally.... would be great if there is a app that does that for me.

Answer (score 1):

For opening the menu (same behaviour as clicking Menu physical button) just use the openOptionsMenu() method of your activity.

Here is a code that open the Menu with a button :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm looking for more of a non-programmatic solution. :) thanks anyway

Comment: Is this link useful for you ? http://www.androidng.com/enable-virtual-buttons-on-android-ics